# How to open reply text box of only selected comment?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

There is a post. In post user can comment and reply as well.
There can be lots of comment. Every comment has reply button. Every reply button has same class `reply`. So, whenever i try to reply certain comment and press reply button. Every comment's reply text box opens. I want to open reply `text box` of selected comment.

I have tried by hiding the `reply form` at first and then it shows up after clicking the reply button. 
Comment id can be passed form the reply button to jquery as well.

```
Blade file
<a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a>
<div class="reply-form">
  <form action="{{route('reply')}}" method="post">
     @csrf
     <input name="reply" type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

```
jquery file
$('.reply-form').hide();
$('.comment-container').delegate(".reply","click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.reply-form').toggle(function(){

  });
})
```

For Every comment there is a button reply with same class name `reply`
So, every reply of comments appear after i `click` one `reply button`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.reply-form').hide();
$('.comment-container').delegate(".reply","click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).find('.reply-form')).toggle(function(){

  });
});
```

Comment: Nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.reply-form').hide();
$('.reply').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var replyForm = $(this).siblings('.reply-form');
   $(replyForm).toggle(function(){

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with change of jquery.

```
Blade file
<a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a>
<div class="reply-form d-none">
  <form action="{{route('reply')}}" method="post">
     @csrf
     <input name="reply" type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

add style for d-none

```
.d-none{display:none;}
```

And jquery as,

```
$(document).on('click','.reply',function(){
   $(this).closest('.reply-form').removeClass("d-none");
   //$(this).closest('.reply-form').toggleClass("d-none"); //second option if want to show and hide
}
```

And Remove href="#" from anchor or add javascript:void(0)